# Can "Zusammenstellung" mean "summary"?

Tags: meaning, german-to-english

As far as I understand, "Zusammenstellung" means a compilation, a grouping of something. That is what I gather from Duden, Wictionary, etc.

But in Linguee, it is also sometimes translated by "summary". To me, a "summary" is a completely different concept as a "compilation". Indeed, with a "summary" one would necessarily lose some substance, while a "compilation" contains the concept of exhaustivity, without losing any of the "elements".

Therefore: can the German word "Zusammenstellung" really mean "summary", or is it just a bad translation in Linguee?

Comment: Dict.cc lists "collocation" as the most frequent translation. This has a number of meanings in English, most rather technical, but none could be confused with "compilation" or "summary".

Comment: Wow, that is a strange one, I would never have thought to "collocation" for "Zusammenstellung"! Thanks RDBury for the reference!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my feeling, "Zusammenfassung" and "Zusammenstellung" are clearly different, I don't see how context might influence this. "Zusammenfassung" = "summary" is about a reduced informational content (or it is a piece of text that has such a kind of content), while "Zusammenstellung" is a combination of things. The latter could also cover bits of information, but "Informationen zusammenstellen" does not entail that the result will be short. You might in turn want a summary for what you get from this *Zusammenstellung*.

PS: I've just noticed something: "Zusammenfassung" can also be used in a sense like "combination / Zusammenstellung" - e.g. "Inhalte zu einem eigenen Kapitel zusammenfassen" (grouping contents as a separate chapter). But this is not a problem for our question, for it doesn't work the other way round: "Zusammenstellung" still cannot mean "summary".

Comment: Thanks Alazon! Based on your explanations, I will prefer "Zusammenfassung" to express a "summary", and keep "Zusammenstellung" for "compilation"!

Answer (score 4):

The question is difficult to answer without context - a concrete sentence or paragraph, where the word is used.

"Zusammenstellung" is a *Verb* (verb) made "*Nomen" (noun). The *Verb* is "zusammenstellen", which itself is a composite word: "zusammen" means "together" and "stellen" which means "to put" or "to position". "Zusamenstellen" means "to put together" (to compile, but sometimes also "to assemble") and a "Zusammenstellung" is the result of this - something which has been put together.

This is usually a "compilation" but sometimes what was put together might be an overview, a summary or similar things. This is why context is important.

So, in the general way you asked, your answer is: it depends. I hope to have made clear what actually it depends on.

Comment: Thanks @bakunin for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

In contrast to what the currently accepted answer claims, there is at least one notable resource that suggests that a *Zusammenstellung* may be used to mean "summary": Here's what [the DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Zusammenstellung) provides as one of two meaning explanations for *Zusammenstellung*:

> **geordnete Übersicht**
>
> Beispiel:
> *das Buch bringt eine übersichtliche Zusammenstellung der wichtigsten Forschungsergebnisse*

The provided example clarifies that in this sense, a *Zusammenstellung* is not just a compilation of **all** relevant findings, but a condensed compilation of only **the most important** ones – or in other words, a summary of the most relevant findings.

Note, however, that *Zusammenfassung* and *Zusammenstellung* are still not fully synonymous. A sentence like *Ich gebe dir mal eine Zusammenstellung des Films von gestern* ("I'll give you a summary of yesterday's movie") is very unidiomatic, while *Zusammenfassung* would be fully acceptable here. My suspicion is that *Zusammenstellung* can be used to mean "summary" in academic genres in particular (as in the DWDS example), but not in more general contexts.

Comment: The difference here is: "Zusammenfassung" means to create a new shortened version of the original content (like a *summary*) and "Zusammenstellung" means to create a *collection* of the original content (possibly omitting some parts).

Comment: @allo: I'm not sure that your distinction will always be valid. Taking the DWDS example, I find it difficult that the intended meaning is that there's a whole book just containing the abbreviated collection of original content. But regardless of that, I'm fairly sure that both meanings can be subsumed under the English word "summary".

Comment: Thanks Schmuddi for your answer! The first & second paragraphs of your answer look a bit strange though, I think you wrote "Zusammenfassung" when you actually meant "Zusammenstellung", oder?

Comment: @SylvainGadenne: You're absolutely right, what a stupid oversight. I'll fix that straight-away.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean the same thing.
I don't know how Linguee works, but it may have found some documents where people put "Zusammenstellung" at or near the end of the document.
If I found that at the end of certain documents (Think receipt type documents with a list of line items), I might very well interpret it as a type of summary. But I don't think it's conventional.

Comment: Thanks Robse for your answer!